# can I send an <img> to an SQL database with an identifier instead of the actual image?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a website that allows people to create matchups guides in video games. In order to create a matchup guide you have to drag specific cards in designated slots to which you would then add helpful text and then upload the "matchup" which consists of the dragged images. I want to upload these images to an sql database which is then placed on a seperate page which displays the put together matchup.  but adding the full image on each user upload feels impractical. Is there a way to only send a representation of the image in the form of something like Var which can then be represented on the next page as an image. Thanks.

Comment: sure you can ... how will the identifier relate to the image?

Comment: You can upload files, save them in a directory and save their URLs to the database, which is the common usage.